# Loading different files into SQL Server with subfolders

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse

I am designing a data warehouse so the first tier is staging, in which I need to load several different files into SQL Server.

I did this things using a ForEach loop container (For loading on type_A of file) --> (connected to other Foreach loop) to load type_B file and other foreach loop to load Type_C files..

I wanted to know if this can be done using a single foreach loop with script task?

This is what I have done :

[image]

I need to know is there a way around to load multiple files using one foreach loop with script task or something ?

the way i did results in lot of variables with many foreachloop taking lot of time :( 
please somebody guide me !

Answer (score 0):

If each file type has different requirements, then I dont think you can get away from multiple For Each Loops.

I would try to disconnect them from each other, so they can run in parallel.  In a typical staging setup there are no dependancies between sources, so they could all run in parallel.  Even on commodity hardware this could be 4x faster.